# iOS: Transition animation with UIBlurEffect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uivisualeffectview

I'm using the UIBlurEffect implemented in iOS 8 to blur the screen easily. However, I'm experiencing a problem since I can't figure out how to make this blur effect into an animation rather than a instant effect.

I tried using this but it didn't work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^
{
    visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];
}];
```

While it did display the effect, it didn't animate throughout the 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing any animation because you didn't *do* anything that animates. UIView animation relies on the use of animatable properties of an existing view. You aren't animating any properties: you are merely calling `addSubview:`.

Comment: So how do I make it animate?

Comment: I don't know what animation you want. What does "it animate" even _mean_? What is your mental picture of what should happen? Start with that and then animate it.

Comment: I just want it to fade out. Let the visualEffectView slowly become subview of self.view

Comment: "Fade" = `alpha` property. No? I mean, start by asking yourself how you would do this if this were not a blur view but just an ordinary view that you wanted to fade.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't think of that even though I used it in previous projects. Thank you very much for suggesting it. After trying it out, it works.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it more the way you wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

First you are defining UIVisualEffectView() and define its frame and after that you can animate the blurView with effect:

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView()
blurView.frame = self.view.bounds

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion